# Changing certain values in html table depending on the input value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with some numbers and an input below it. I need to change the values in the table depending on the input value. With different %s for different input values (eg. 0=1%, 1=5%, 3=10% etc.) that affect certain defined cells only.

[what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UC1nv.png)

So if the input value is 0, then the values are default. If the input value is 1 then it affects certain cells (takes the default value and adds a certain % to it)
[what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aogsZ.png)

So far I've only managed to connect the input value with a set values for the output in cells, but I can't figure out how to take the default value and do the math operation on it. My attempts were just giving me blanks.

My js:

```
function myFunction();
var v = document.querySelector("td-value");
var x = document.getElementById("input-value");
var i = x.value;
var value0 = 34;
var value1 = 55;

  if (i == 0) {
    document.getElementById("td-value").innerHTML = value0;
  }
  if (i == 1) {
    document.getElementById("td-value").innerHTML = value1;
  }
}
```

My html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table>
<td id="td-value">34</td>
</table>

<input id="input-value" oninput=myFunction() type="number" value="0" min="0" max="15">
</body>
</html>
```

Scouring the internet for the answer didn't lead me anywhere sadly and all my attempts seemed hopeless. Adding math functions to the "v" didn't work at all, it either broke the function or gave blank results.

Comment: Nvm, managed to get it to work

Comment: Then you should post your answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Aight then, the approach with a simple  was wrong it seems, I don't have a lot of knowledge to fully explain why tho.  even with set values wouldn't accept any arguments necessary for this to work, so they would output either undefined, nan, or no values at all. So I thought about using  instead, which seemed to work, although the values still needed to be parsed, so that's what I did. Then connected the armguments from input to the data id's from the table and applied a bunch of math to them.

```html
<table>
<td>Damage</td>
<td><data id="dmg.max" value="34">34</data></td>
</table>
<input id="level" type="number" oninput=upgrade_level_ar() name="level1" min="0" max="15" value="0">
```

as for the script, first setup a bunch of values to use, data for the input and if functions and that's pretty much it.

```js
function upgrade_level_ar() {
  var dmax = document.getElementById("dmg.max");
  var dmin = document.getElementById("dmg.min");
// input
  var x = document.getElementById("level");
  var cVal = x.value;
//base/default values
  var max_bd_Val = document.getElementById("dmg.max").value;
  var min_bd_Val = document.getElementById("dmg.min").value;
//formula for %
  const l1 = (parseInt(max_bd_Val) + (parseInt(max_bd_Val) * 0.61 / 100));

  const dmin1 = (parseInt(min_bd_Val) + (parseInt(min_bd_Val) * 0.61 / 100));
//if function for the number from the input
  if (cVal == 0) {
    dmax.innerHTML = max_bd_Val;
    dmin.innerHTML = min_bd_Val;
  }
  if (cVal == 1) {
    dmax.innerHTML = l1.toFixed(1);
    dmin.innerHTML = dmin1.toFixed(1);
  }
}
```

I have almost no programming background/experience, so I'm pretty sure it's not the best way to deal with this problem or the most optimized code idk, but it worked out for me. Hope this helps someone. I cut the code tho, not all the id's/values, because they are mostly repetitive.